# Cassandra have slow(rpc timeout) read request with long IN operator

Tags: nosql, cassandra, bigdata, cql, high-load

I have next table structure:

```
SELECT * FROM v WHERE uid = 0x5103be34e695ba3c31000000;

 uid                        | cid       | v
----------------------------+-----------+-------
 0x5103be34e695ba3c31000000 | 02j1Dy9G1 |  True
 0x5103be34e695ba3c31000000 | 03szNx7G1 | False
 0x5103be34e695ba3c31000000 | 0SREjO9G1 |  True
 0x5103be34e695ba3c31000000 | 0bQ4Qn9G1 |  True
 0x5103be34e695ba3c31000000 | 0ojEVLWF1 |  True
 0x5103be34e695ba3c31000000 | 1NiWfO9G1 |  True
 0x5103be34e695ba3c31000000 | 1fSmhWGF1 |  True
 0x5103be34e695ba3c31000000 | 1o0Ri3TF1 |  True
```

User (uid) likes(True) or dislikes(False) content (cid)

"Is content liked by user?"

```
SELECT * FROM v WHERE uid = 0x5103be34e695ba3c31000000 AND cid IN ('Rqy9V79J',....more than 2000 cids...);

rpc timeout

Normal SELECT * FROM v WHERE uid = 0x5103be34e695ba3c31000000 works very fast.
```

How can i speed up read request with IN? Other data structure? 
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your full schema (create table statement) including any indexes?

Comment: How many instances in your cluster?  If you have more than one, set consistency to local_quorum and see if you have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

IN-operator with many parameters require more memory for each thread.

To fix it try to set JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss512k"